# ¿Cambiar base de datos mediante parámetros?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentando crear una consulta, la cual me permite cambiar de base de datos mediante un parámetro hasta el momento lo que he intentado es;

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @codbodega varchar(5)
DECLARE  @dbase sysname




SELECT TOP 1 @codbodega = codbodega FROM vista_saldos_fecha 

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @codbodega + ' FROM vista_saldos_fecha where codigo=''PT-1485'''
SET @dbase ='nombre_db'
EXEC (@sqlCommand , @dbase)
```

la consulta se ejecuta, pero no retorna datos , ni cambia base de datos

o como más puedo realizar este proceso?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes concatenar la variable de la base a la misma consulta del `select`:

```
SET @dbase ='nombre_db'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @dbase + '..' + @codbodega + ' 
                          FROM vista_saldos_fecha where codigo=''PT-1485'''

EXEC(@sqlCommand)
```

Recuerda que este tipo de sentencias son suceptibles de sufrir inyección de SQL, por lo que lo mejor siempre es que el motor controle los parámetros ingresados, en tu caso `@codbodega`, para esto te recomiendo el uso de [`sp_executesql()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, estuve validando y haciendo pruebas y funciono, me demore en contestar porque ahi demasiado trabajo, pero gracias...